# Surround Field from JSON with quotes

Tags: shell-script, sed, json, jq

I want to change a field in json from number to string format.

I create the json output from a dynamical created text file like this:

```
LastUpdate=2019-12-01T13:26:46.388817319+01:00
State=NOT OK
TempA=26.299999
TempB=-0.100000
PumpState=0
Vault=100.000000
Mode=H+WW
ErrState=0
```

then I use `jo` to convert this output to json

```
cat /tmp/file | jo -p 
{
   "LastUpdate": "2019-12-01T13:26:46.388817319+01:00",
   "State": "NOT OK",
   "TempA": 26.299999,
   "TempB": -0.1,
   "PumpState": 0,
   "Vault": 100,
   "Mode": "H+WW",
   "ErrState": 0
}
```

Problem is, that I need the value `ErrState` to be in string format.

It looks like `jo` cant do it on piped input. So I was thinking it is maybe possible with `sed` or `jq`? Or any other tool?

Problem could be, that Output from ErrState can change to text, than I will have two times quotes on a simple search & replace.

Remember I want to keep the full output - only change ErrState to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `jq` you can use:

```
.ErrState = (.ErrState | tostring)
```

Comment: hmm.. not bad - but it change 0 to null

Comment: ok, only on the only version from jq play - in the script that works THANKS :)

Comment: edit: online version from jq play ;)